# Rolify Table Error (user.add_role :admin Unknown Key Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, key, cancancan, rolify

I'm attempting to setup the rolify gem and I'm running into an issue assigning a role to a user in the console.

Here's my error:

```
2.2.1 :007 > user.add_role :admin
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :optional.
```

I'm running devise with cancancan and rolify. I'm also running the Koudoku gem for subscription payment support. I'm suspecting this error might be caused by the fact that my "subscriptions" table also has a "user_id" column. Is there anything I can do to correct this issue?

Here's my schema.

```
create_table "subscriptions", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "stripe_id"
t.integer  "plan_id"
t.string   "last_four"
t.integer  "coupon_id"
t.string   "card_type"
t.float    "current_price"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "string"
t.string   "last_name"
end

 add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
 add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name:    
 "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

create_table "users_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "role_id"
end

add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], name:   "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"

end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Rolify role generator generates Role model with following code:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base


has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

The `:optional => true` parameter is supported in Rails version 5 and above. To get around this issue, just delete that line from your Role model and you should be good to go. Below is final code for your reference:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a really good gem, but disappointed that this sort of thing isn't handled out the box, especially given how many apps use Rails version < 5